# How to print name of array in php

Tags: php, mysql

The array below won't fire I've been looking at this problem for hours and cannot seems to figure out how to print the names.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <?php 
         $listResult = executeQuery("SELECT fname, lname FROM SPIFF_log WHERE id = '" . $array[id] . "'") or die("Bad query");

         while ($listArray = $listResult->fetch_assoc()) {
               $string =  "<h4>". $listArray['fname'] . " " . $listArray['lname'] ."</h4>";

               echo "<p>Hello</p>" . $string . "";
                                        }
     ?>
</div>
```

I expect to return a string saying `"Hello fname, lname"`.

Comment: Where is the code for `executeQuery()`?  You're not checking its return value: are you getting any results?

Comment: Its a method from php already predefined method to execute SQL queries.

Comment: Well, I'd never heard of it until now, probably because it's not been updated since 2012. One has to ask why you're using the PEAR library for MySQL access instead of the more common Mysqli() or PDO functions. Nevertheless, have you verified that your call to executeQuery() actually returns data, and not an error status?